# How to specify a custom rostoolchain.cmake when compiling with catkin?

Tags: robotic-arm, catkin-make, cross-compiling

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to cross-compile ROS for ARM on my x86-64 laptop. To do this, I'm trying to run `catkin_make_isolated` with this rostoolchain.cmake file:

```
#File rostoolchain.cmake
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

# Have to set this one to BOTH, to allow CMake to find rospack
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

And I'm calling it like:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/rostoolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /tmp/ros/$ROS_DISTRO -j1
```

However, the output reports:

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
```

and the compiler shown is "GNU GCC" instead of "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc", implying my custom cmake file is being ignored.

How do I fix this? What's the proper way to cross-compile ROS for ARM on x86?

There's almost no documentation of this in the wiki. I found [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/CrossCompiling), but it's not very descriptive and hasn't been updated in three years.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254059/how-to-specify-a-custom-rostoolchain.cmake-when-compiling-with-catkin?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [meta-ros](https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros) layer for OpenEmbedded is able to cross-compile a large number of important ROS packages, and it is easy to add recipes for new packages if needed.

---

Originally posted by [PeterHousel](https://answers.ros.org/users/917/peterhousel/) with karma: 26 on 2017-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1